# what kind of server used by IOT?

Tags: server, iot

I am an engineering student and I'm doing a final internship study on IOT (Internet Of Things) using Cassandra as DBMS and a generic server.

I want to know what kind of server used by IOT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for directions more than anything else.

Taking into consideration that IoT is in its infancy, I suggest that you start by looking at some proposed block diagrams for an **IoT Solution**. [Eclipse IoT](http://iot.eclipse.org/java/open-iot-stack-for-java.html) and [ARM mbed](http://mbed.org/technology/os/) provide a nice diagrams laying out typical blocks of an **IoT Solution**.

For me, there are three typical types of components in each **IoT Solution**:

- The **Things** that are the *leaf* of an **IoT Solution**. A **Thing** is any object that has a specific purpose contributing to a larger purpose. To accomplish its purpose, it may need to talk to other **Things** or it may be needed to report its work to other **Things** or a **Server**. A **Thing** could be a very small gadget that senses a physical phenomenon, a consumer machine like a your home fridge or your home TV, or a full fledged industrial machines.
- The **Servers** that are the *center*. There might be different purposes for this type of component. I can list here at least: administration, monitoring and Data gathering and analysis.
- The **Gateways** that are the *intermediate* between the **Things** and the **Servers**. The purpose of this type of component is to facilitate the connection of the **Things** to the **Servers**. By its nature, an **IoT Solution** will operate in wide area (hence the contribution of Internet). In addition, the **Things** would have limited communication capabilities. As such, the **Gateway** will be here to 'assist' **Things** while connecting to the **Server**.

As I said in the beginning, IoT is in its infancy. The above described solution is a *Typical Solution* as of now, and it is far from being the *Solution*. However, I hope it will give you some insight in order to found your direction.

At the end, please note that, as of now, I see two types of propositions for Open Source **IoT Servers**:

- [Eclipse IoT](http://iot.eclipse.org/frameworks.html), [WSO2](http://wso2.com/) and [RedHat](http://www.redhat.com/embedded/) offer generic frameworks that would be used to develop specific servers
- [Eclipse SmartHome](https://eclipse.org/smarthome/) and [Eclipse Scada](https://eclipse.org/eclipsescada/) that offer servers ready for specific need

Comment: what you meant by used to develop specific servers ?

Comment: Eclipse IoT, for instance, provides the MQTT broker 'Eclipse Mosquitto', The CoAP server 'Eclipse Californium', and the LWM2M server 'Leshan'. All this systems can be used to develop IoT solutions. They are not packaged solutions that are ready-for-use by end users.
So, for a specific domain (please keep in mind, the IoT covers a huge spectrum of needs), you will come up with a solution developed by you (Business Rules, UI, ...) that takes full advantage of specialized systems (DBMS, MQTT Broker, CoAP Server, LWM2M Server, Big Data Server, ...).

Comment: thank you
and for Eclipse SmartHome and Eclipse Scada  provides what?

Comment: These are two [packaged solutions](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/pre-packaged+software) that are ready-for-use (almost for Eclipse Scada) by end user that targets specific needs. Eclipse SmartHome is tuned to easy implementation of SmartHome solutions: this type of solutions target the automation of daily life in a Home: you can program your mobile to activate AC at your Home when you are 5 min away from your home while coming from Work by car.

Comment: Here is a nice presentation of an [End-to-end IoT](https://www.parleys.com/talk/543f8e75e4b06e1184ae4115) solution given by the IoT team at Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Internet of Things does not need to have a central server. Actually, it will be much better in terms of privacy to have decentralized IoT networks, where user data is stored in their private clouds and federated using open protocols. This is the reasoning behind the [PrIoT Manifesto](https://github.com/niutech/priot).

Comment: I fully support your initiative. It is important that IoT is under the control of people rather than a means to control people. IoT solution should be secure to use and should protect people's privacy.